# how to get Linkedin person id for V2 api?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to post on my LinkedIn profile through Linkedin V2 API. It keeps returning an error

> Request Error: com.linkedin.publishing.util.common.ResponseException:
>   Writers of type person are not authorized to modify
>   UserGeneratedContent..

maybe this is happening because I didn't send my LinkedIn person id.

```
$author = array(
            'author' => 'urn:li:person:XXXXXXXX',
        );
```

How can i find my linkedin profile's Person id?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Profile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api) to [Retrieve Current Member's Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api#retrieve-current-members-profile). In the Section about the [Person ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api#person-id):

> The `id` returned in the response is the unique identifier of the user

You can also use [fields projection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/projections?context=linkedin/compliance/context) in order to retrieve only the `id` field, as example:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
"https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id)"
```

will return:

```
{
  "id": "yrZCpj2Z12"
}
```